# unable to open setting of HAME A8 3g router

Tags: networking

I'm unable to to open setting of HAME A8 3g router through internet explorer using 192.168.169.1 i.e the default ip address of the this router. How can I know the set ip address of this router???

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is probably on a different subnet.

Two solutions:

- Add a route to 192.168.169.0/24,
- or add an IP alias on your interface at 192.168.169.2 subnet 255.255.255.0